# Batch Delete with checkpoint still causes log growth

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a large table (600 million rows,  60GB data) that I need to migrate to another table. This is for a few reasons:

- The current table is a heap and I want to convert it to having a clustered index
- I have a column which is time(7) that only really needs to be time(4)
- The table has previous deleted columns that are still reserving space from what I can see (they are just marked as is_dropped in the metadata.

The best way I could come up with doing all this in the fewest operations (i.e. not having to rebuild the table multiple times) was to create a new table with the column definitions I want and copy the data across into the new table while deleting the old data, followed by a name switch. I've split this into batches in a loop to prevent the log file growing continously, however this doesn't seem to be working and after about 70million rows, the log file has grown to around 110GB and there is no space left on the server...

The database is using simple recovery and I have a checkpoint after each batch, which I thought was meant to stop the log file growing! Am I missing something, or is there some other reason my log file continues to grow? This is testing on a dev server I'm doing, so there are no other operations currently running on the table.

My query is:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1000000) FROM RunningData with (tablock)
    OUTPUT 
        deleted.[Data], 
        deleted.[Date], 
        deleted.Time, 
        deleted.Category, 
        deleted.SystemID
    INTO [dbo].[TmpRunningData] (
        Data,
        Date,
        [Time],
        Category,
        SystemID
    )

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
    CHECKPOINT
    RAISERROR ('Moving to next batch', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    waitfor delay '00:00:01'
END
```

I really want to be able to sort this table out, but I'm struggling to find a way of processing this table due to the size! Any suggestions on how I can stop the log growing, or another way to do it would be very appreciated, thanks! In production the database can go down for a weekend, so there should be plenty of time to do it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my server and the checkpoint is clearing the log. Have you try with smaller batches ?

Comment: I agree with @DominiqueBoucher, try using a much smaller batch size, and then see how much the log is growing. Depending on how wide your table is, 1million rows could be quite a lot of data.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added originally, I have tried different batch sizes - I was originally using 100k at a time which also saw the issue after about the same period of time - I would have thought if the transaction log can handle one batch, it should be okay looping through with the checkpoint though?

Comment: In theory it should yes... When I reproduce it on my server (with a longer wait before each batch), I can see the log getting filled and then when it hit the checkpoint it cleared itself. Give it a try with a 5 sec wait and 100 000 rows batch and let us know if you still have the issue. If you do, then increase the wait to, let's say 1 min and during this minute, look at the sys.databases like Tibor suggested in his answer to make sure there is not something else preventig the log from truncating.

Answer (score 4):

First step is to ask SQL Server why the log grows. You should find the answer in the log_reuse_wait_desc column in the sys.databases catalog view. Being in simple mode, it shouldn't be log backup. Then take it from there.

And don't do it all in one transaction, since SQL Server can't truncate past the oldest open transaction.

Comment: Whilst running, it is set to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION' for the DB, which seems expected as this is all happening within a transaction

Comment: SQL Server can never truncate the log past the oldest active transaction - it wouldn't be able to rollback if it did. So if all your work is transaction protected (which we didn't see in the code you posted), then you gain nothing from your batching.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's what I've missed, I assumed checkpoint worked with the transaction. I guess that means there's no way of doing a "dry" test run then and I just have to "commit" to it! Thanks for the help, this is probably why electronic engineers shouldn't be made into dbas also!

Comment: Haha! Don't beat yourself up about it. :-) But, yeah, you can't have the cake and eat it, I'm afraid. If you were on SQL Server 2019 you *could* play with Accelerated Database Recovery, but I'm not sure it would help and possibly overkill for your case.

Comment: Yeah, now I think about it logically there's no magic that can happen - if I want to rollback I have to store all the data to do so somewhere...